# What is "average recieved signal power over bandwidth"?

Tags: signal, bandwidth

I came across to Shannon’s formula for calculating channel capacity and I don’t quite understand why we calculate average signal power… “over bandwidth”. Why over that "domain of interest"?

Here is my interpretation why but I’m not sure if I understood it right.

Imagine we are sending some signal f(t) from point A to point B. We take FT (Fourier transform) of signal f(t) at point A, and we get ourselves all the sinusoid components of that signal. For every component of that signal in frequency domain we have particular value of amplitude. Now, I’m not sure if this can be done but here is my interpretation of “power over bandwidth”: “Inside frequency domain” we calculate avg. power of signal in such fashion that we calculate power of every component of signal and by doing some manipulations with all those calculated “powers” (sum of them equals power of signal in time domain?) we can calculate average power of the signal in frequency domain.

So we have avg. power of “clear/undistorted signal” of value for example 40[W] “over bandwidth” that interest us (bandwidth of our signal).

Signal traveling from point A to receiver side B gets distorted. At point B we take FT of that distorted signal. Now, maybe we have some components of signal that are added within our signal, so all those components represent “noise signal”. We “separate” noise components and our signal components (in our head). Since signal is distorted maybe some of the amplitudes of signal’s components are now changed, so we again calculate (in a same fashion as one above) average power of that components and get… maybe some different average power which for example might be less than one at point A.

So, based on this interpretation do we by that mean average signal power “over bandwidth” (“over bandwidth of something that interests us, over our signal bandwidth to see if something has changed”)?

Comment: I suggest that you split the "wall of text" 2nd paragraph into a few paragraphs just by adding a few empty lines. That would make things so much more readable.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Hope it now looks better!

Comment: Well, if you didn't specify a BW then you'd need to take into account "everything" so also noise over an infinite BW. That makes things complicated so in order to "limit our view" we define a BW and look at the power in that BW. This does not so much concern itself with transmitting or distorting a signal as in your example, that's not needed. A certain (average) power in a certain BW is just a way of describing the power of a signal in a certain frequency band. This also helps describing the S/N ratio which needs to be good enough to extract the data.

Comment: Are you basically asking for an explanation of the shannon formula?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ok. So, if I understood you right that makes things much easier in a sense: if we define same BW at the receive end, then no components other than "signal" ones we don't need to get into account or should I say "interpret". We limit ourselves to the spectrum of a signal and see what happens with frequency components. Now, this might sound stupid but what is the point of "filters" at the receiver end if we can just manipulate  signal in a such sense that we decrease/increase amplitudes of some components and get ourselves "orginal signal". PS: I'm newbie.

Comment: What if your friend has a device that is loudly transmitting just next to the frequency band you're listening on and you're listening to a very weak signal. Receivers have a **limited dynamic range** so it cannot receive both (weak and strong) signals at the same time. The weak signal would be "drowned" (it would disappear in the noise as the gain is lowered in the receiver so that the strong signal does not cause clipping) by the the strong signal. That's where filters come in. We can **filter out** the unwanted strong signal so that we receive the weak signal better.

Comment: @Andyaka well, sort of. I understand some factors but don't understand part average power "over bandwidth". That's all (for now).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I think you explained it really good but at the same time I feel stupid by not getting it. Let's have an example to see where my logical flaw is. If you have signal which represents my voice which has low amplitudes (very week signal), and you have voice signal of my friend with higher amplitudes, and you have frequency bandwidth that can receive all voice components. Then, how I'm going to make filter which will "filter out" strong signal? Please try to explain me in terms "what my filter will do in frequency domain to filter out strong signal".

Comment: Nope, doesn't work like that. Speech is not a good example as it uses one and the same frequency band. Filters cannot separate signals based on **amplitude**, they can only separate signals out based on their **frequency**. Information can be transmitted my **modulating** a certain frequency. I can use two frequencies for two different information streams and use filters to separate the two. A filter is like the filter in a loudspeaker box with 2 or 3 speakers. The tweeter only gets the high frequencies. The woofer only gets the low frequencies.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ok. So, for example you are modulating weak and strong signals with two different sets of carrier frequencies (imagine AM for sake of a simplicity). For weaker signals we use some set of carrier frequencies and for stronger ones we use different set of frequencies. In order to filter them at the reciever end (in our example: to receive only "weaker signals") you say "okay let's just make filter where only carrier frequencies bellow ... something can be demodulated". Are we now safe of "drowning" of weak signal as you mentioned earlier?

Comment: Yes, because by using a filter we have now isolated the weak signal. Now we can amplify and demodulate it. Without the filtering the stronger signal would still be present. If we would then still amplify the signal to be able to see the weak signal, the strong signal would cause the amplifier to "clip" (it would need to output more signal than it can provide) that distorts the signal and **all** information is lost.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Part 1: Nice! Okay, we received signal without the fear of interfering with strong one, but somehow noise distorted it and we demodulated signal which is distorted picture of original signal. If we take Fourier analysis of that signal, does it contains component's from the "noise signal" which we can get rid of in order to "back our signal to original shape"?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Part 2: Do we, based on that "noise components" can recreate the function which represents "noise signal" and calculate average noise power at the receive end over BW? At what point do we calculate avg. power of signal over BW? When we receive it, demodulate it and take avg power of "distorted" signal or when we clear it from "noise"?

Comment: P1: depends on the S/N (Signal/Noise) ratio, modulation type and demodulator. The S/N needs to be high enough for the demod. to be able to retrieve the information. If S/N is too low, errors will occur. So the signal does not need to be restored to "original" it just needs to be "good enough".

Comment: P2: it is **impossible** to treat the noise differently and noise is **an unpredictable signal** (it is random). So unless you know the original signal (which you don't, only the transmitter has it) you cannot remove the noise. Again S/N needs to be good enough and that's it. So receiver power is Signal + Noise.

Comment: Interesting fact: for GPS signals S/N can be such that the Noise is larger than the signal ! How do we retrieve the data then ? By receiving the same data several times and **averaging**. Since the noise is random, averaging lowers the noise. But the information we want repeats so it will not average out. So averaging increases S/N.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Nice!!! Thanks for sharing that fact! What an awesome idea for tackling that problem. But if you can make transmitter to do real time fourier analysis and send that information to receiver then send your signal, then receiver use that information as a reference to make such modifications to signal received then the noise can be "deleted" theorethicaly? Final answer, for calculating average noise over bandwidth we use some "models" that best represents noise from point A to point B, and then we calculate S/N ratio, or what is the function on which we calculate this N factor?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I mean I know it only needs to get good S/N as you mentioned, but would it be nice to make step further and get rid of "noise factor" maybe...

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie But... how much (S/N)'s is optimal for averaging? The more the better or it doesn't depend?

Comment: Delete noise, nope, does not work. Also noise cannot be "pre compensated" as noise is unpredictable. The noise is never the same. The noise is a given and the sum of all noise sources. In wireless receivers the amplifier just after the antenna often determines the noise as the signal is so small at that point. Noise is inherent and you cannot eliminate it in practice. If you could then you could transmit information at extremely low power and still receive it. But that's impossible.

Comment: No there is no optimum S/N for Averaging, it is independent. As long as the data repeats so that you get the same data multiple times averaging will work.

Comment: @Bimpelrekie Nice! Thank you for your time and a very, very constructive answers!

Answer (score 1):

First to your question: The term "Average received signal power over bandwidth" is the [power spectral density](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) (PSD), usually in unit dBm/Hz or W/Hz. It cannot be used directly to calculate channel capacity, it's prime use is to calculate [interference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference).

For discussion of channel capacity, it is important we are not dealing with "distortion" (which would be counteracted by pre-distortion and line coding), but with additional noise. There are different sources of noise with different spectra, but for discussion of channel coding it is sufficient to look at  [additional white gaussian noise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise) (AWGN), a memoryless stochastic process totally uncorrelated to your signal.

AWGN has in infinite bandwidth, but limited [radiant intensity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_intensity). This opens the door to reduction of total received noise power while keeping the full total received signal power, thus improving SNR.

- Your signal will be received from a certain direction. By using directive antennae, you reduce the solid angle for noise while retaining all of the signal (antenna gain)
- Your signal will only occupy a limited bandwidth. By filtering, you reduce the total received noise power while retaining all of the received signal power. Noise spectral density over the "bandwidth of interest" will determine the noise power
- Some processes/components in your receiver will add more noise than they amplify your signal. This is expressed as [noise figure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_figure) of this process/component.
- Noise spectral density depends on temperature, cooling lowers the density and thus also the total power.
- Some tricks allow you to reduce your signals occupied bandwidth while retaining its power, making bandwidth filtering even more efficient (spread-spectrum processing gain).

At each reference point in your receiver, you are able to divide total signal by noise power and tell a [signal to noise ratio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) (SNR), typically in decibels. Important for channel capacity is the SNR before channel decoding. Now Shannon comes into play.

He states that information can be transferred as long as the SNR (in dB) is \$>-\infty\$. A common misunderstanding is that SNR > 0 is required, but this is just the point where detection and demodulation of the signal become very easy. Detection is harder for SNR < 0 but still any deviation from a pure stochastic process is detectable. The reasoning that information transfer with arbitrary low bit error rate is possible for every SNR is quite surprising and makes Shannons original article an interesting read.

The rate at which information can be transferred is however limited and Shannon is able to proove an upper bound for this rate. It depends on occupied bandwidth, which is related to maximum slew rate (think of [Fourier decomposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis)) and minimum temporal spacing of symbols, and the SNR, requiring a minimum symbol distinctness and limiting bits per symbol.

The Shannon-Limit is a theoretical upper bound, channel codes with near maximum performance are still an active field of research. [LPDC-Codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-density_parity-check_code) and [Turbo-Codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_code) are the best known solutions.

Comment: Nice! I have a couple of questions: part 1: „It cannot be used directly to calculate channel capacity, it's prime use is to calculate interference.“
how does it tells me if there was some interference? example: if I sent 40[W] signal and recieved 40[W] signal power but signal was distorted, how would it tell me if there was interference?

Comment: part 2: what does „signal is uncorellated with noise signal“ tells me about signal and that noise in some simpler terms? what is generalization of idea of „correlation“? what are the benefits if two signals are uncorellated if they somehow „meet“ with one another during transmission?

Comment: part 3: „AWGN has limited radiant intensity“. so if I „direct a beam of radiation“ in some „V shape“ away from antena (directional antena) then if I lower that „V angle“, AWGN's radiant intensity will be lower (they are directly proportional?). that will imply that Noise power will be lower and so S/N is bigger. so if we lower „V angle“ that means that „beam“ will be „less exposed to outside noises (AWGN)“ aka „AWGN has limited radiant intensity“

Comment: part 4: „By filtering, you reduce the total received noise power while retaining all of the received signal power“ when you recieve signal with some frequency components then what are you trying to filter there in order to reduce total recieved noise power? imagine you've done Fourier deomposition of signal at recieve end. what are you trying to filter there?

Comment: @Krushe EMC regulation limits the allowed power spectral density (to put it short). This is because it is not know a priori which part of the spectrum causes the interference. "Density" and "total power" are mathematically related (total is the integral of density over bandwidth), but for calculation of SNR, you need total power. Note: Interference is the interaction of your mobile with your TV set, distortion is about the non-linearities between the TV station and your TV set and noise is what your TV set receives from cosmic background etc. Shannon capacity is about noise, not distortion.

Comment: @Krushe ad 2: The rules for adding power of correlated signals are somewhat different. Noise is per se uncorrelated, I should have omitted "uncorrelated".

Comment: @Krushe ad 3: Yes, limiting the solid angle with a directional antenna will lower the total noise power and improve SNR. I added the word "limited", because the noise power received with an isotropic antenna over the full spectrum is **not** infinite, this is not self-evident.

Comment: @Krushe ad 4: No receiver can do a continous fourier transform over an unlimited bandwidth. When you do an discrete fourier transform, you need to sample and quantize, so you already have filtered somewhere before doing that transform.